# React Redux Push object in nested array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

How to push new message in array of connections from reducer? I tried to find right connection by index and then to push it, but can't get to work. 
Connections schema is for example:

```
_id: 3213213,
messages:[...]
```

Messages schema is for example:

```
_id: 123213,
author: '12312321',
body: 'Hi!'
```

So need to find right Connection from array of connections and then to push it in messages array inside that connection

Problem code:

```
const messagesReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECIEVE_CONNECTIONS:
      return action.payload;
    case UPDATE_MESSAGES:
      let index = state.findIndex(
      connection => connection._id === action.update.id
      );
      return [...state, state[index].messages.concat(action.update.message)];
   default:
    return state;
   }
};

export default messagesReducer;
```

Comment: What does a message look like? Is there a unique property you can use to identify it?

Comment: @James I send that message to the backend where it is saved and another to the this reducer to get faster UI update. When user open Messages page RECIEVE_CONNECTIONS is activated and grab all messages from database, but   UPDATE_MESSAGES is for fast update redux and UI

Comment: @UrosKalajdzic if messages in an array , just push to it , instead of concat, like this - state[index].messages.push(action.update.message)

Comment: @UrosKalajdzic ah ok, and is `state` an array of connections?

Comment: @James yes, state is array of connections and messages are array in connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually updating the state with this line:

```
return [...state, state[index].messages.concat(action.update.message)];
```

You are actually corrupting your Redux state as `state` is a list of connections, and here you are including the concatenated list of messages.

Here's an example which keeps your state *relatively* immutable (if you want full immutability you would need to also clone all the existing connections / messages, in this example I'm simply copying the array)

```
let index = state.findIndex(
  connection => connection._id === action.update.id
);
const conn = state[index];
const messages = [ ...conn.messages, action.update.message ];
const newState = state.slice();
newState[index] = { ...conn, messages };
return newState;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const messagesReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECIEVE_CONNECTIONS:
      return action.payload;
    case UPDATE_MESSAGES:
      // identify the index to update
      const index = state.findIndex(
        connection => connection._id === action.update.id
      );

      // create the new list of messages for the connection
      const messages = state[index].messages.concat(action.update.message)

      // modify the connection at index without modifying state
      const modifiedConnection = Object.assign({}, state[index], { messages });

      // replace the connection at index with the modified connection containing the new message
      return Object.assign([], state, { [index]: modifiedConnection });

   default:
    return state;
   }
};
```

You were close, but you were adding to the list of connections when you really wanted to be adding to a nested list of messages for a specific connection.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it. Might be a little verbose, but I think you'll understand it better this way. This is also fully immutable.

```
const messageToAdd = {
  _id: "xxx",
  body: "new message",
  author: "bar"
};

const index = state.findIndex(
  connection => connection._id === action.update.id
);

const connectionToUpdate = {
  ...state.slice(index, index + 1)[0]
};

const updatedMessagesArr = [
  ...connectionToUpdate.messages,
  messageToAdd
];

const updatedConnection = {
  ...connectionToUpdate,
  messages: updatedMessagesArr
};

return = [
  ...state.slice(0, index),
  updatedConnection,
  ...state.slice(index + 1)
];
```

Comment: `...[messageToAdd]` - why are you creating an array only to spread it? Just pass `messageToAdd`

Comment: Oops, I had changed some stuff around and meant to do that. Thanks.